# Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException HResult=0x80131500 Message=Url is not a valid URL: https://localhost:44300/TwimlResponse.ashx?code=87359179

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

This code to throws Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException Url is not a valid URL:

```
            var call = CallResource.Create(
                url: new Uri("https://localhost:44300/TwimlResponse.ashx?code=87359179"),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+16509661950"),
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phonenumber)
            );
```

This is a perfectly valid url. I do not understand why this exception is being thrown? Can't the webhook url make a call to ashx page on a specific port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook URL can make requests to a page on a specific port number. What it cannot do is make requests to your localhost.

You need to expose that localhost URL to the public internet somehow. One way is by using a tunnelling service. I [personally like](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to do this.

You can use ngrok by [downloading it](https://ngrok.com/download) then, in this case, calling

```
ngrok http 44300
```

If you are running Windows, then you may need [more detail available in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-use-ngrok-windows-and-visual-studio-test-webhooks).

Once you have ngrok running and forwarding to your localhost port, you will be given a URL that looks like `https://RANDOM_SUBDOMAIN.ngrok.io` and you can use that URL in place of `localhost:44300` as above.